# Why do C++ standards introduce more output methods without input counterparts?

Tags: c++, io, c++20

C++20 introduces `<format>`(and sooner C++23 introduces `<print>`). I like those methods, and I always try to use `std::format` when it's supported rather than use a series of `<<`.

But I notice that this evolution seems to only appear in the output. Why isn't there something like `<scan>` for input?

Comment: What would your hypothetical `scan` do that `>>` does not?

Comment: This is not really the kind of question that can reasonably be answered on this site.

Comment: @MarkRansom I imagine it would be the analog to `scanf`, so it would make doing `cin >> scan("%d,%d,%d", a, b, c)` a lot easier on the eyes than `cin >> a; cin.get(); cin >> b; cin.get(); cin >> c`

Comment: @DavidG you know you can chain those, right?  It can be expressed as `cin >> a >> b >> c`.

Comment: A closer parallel to that scanf would be `char sep; if ((cin >> a >> sep) && sep == ',' && (cin >> b >> sep) && sep == ',' && (cin >> c)) ...` which certainly is obnoxious. I would typically use stringstreams and/or regex for any non-trivial formatted input. Curious to see any future developments of a standard for formatted input though.

Comment: Without being able to read minds of the standardisation committee, it's hard to know. But, practically, programmers often need to quite precisely specify text output (e.g. for aesthetics to suit a human who will examine the output) so need ways to control that, but code reading input needs to deal with considerable variability (e.g. if writing two hex values, output of the form "AB, 4C" (all uppercase, not too much whitespace) may matter, but code that reads two hex values often needs to accept varying input by default e.g. "AB,4C" or "Ab 4C" or "aB, <tab><tab>4c" so control is less urgent.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- it's more subtle than that because the input values are, apparently, separated by commas.

Comment: @MarkRansom There's a comma between those integers. So the best you can do is `cin >> a >> sep >> b >> sep >> c`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::format` and `std::print` are already quite a big library additions in themselves and I could imagine that the limited resources for the standard committee to consider the addition of additional features didn't allow them to consider an input equivalent at the same time.

It might also be that the committee wanted to collect more experience with `std::format`/`std::print` first before adding an input equivalent or that there are objections to such an addition in principle, in the proposed implementation details or the priority of such an addition.

I couldn't find any definitive statements pointing towards any of these directions and I have no insider knowledge.

Anyway, the committee is still considering a `std::scan` proposal as follow-up to the `std::format` proposal, see https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/493 for a log of the procedure the proposal has gone through so far. You can also see there polls on design directions, etc. There seems to not have been much activity since 2019, but I am not sure whether this really means anything or not.

In a reddit thread [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/t3q7kj/comment/hywbn2f/) from March 2022, Elias Kosunen, one of the authors of the proposal and author of [scnlib](https://github.com/eliaskosunen/scnlib) mentions that there are still some unsure design questions that need to be made sure of before going forward with the proposal, hoping to be able to target C++26, but acknowledging that a farther delay would be preferable to adding a "half-baked" design to the standard.

As of february 2023, the proposal is still marked "needs-revision", presumably waiting for the author to proceed with it.